# a href tag is not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, href, internet-explorer-11

I am creating a button using a href tag in my page which is working fine in chrome. but it is not at all working in internet explorer the code for the button is

```
 <td class='swMntTopMenu' style="text-align:right">
  <button style="background-color:rgb(255,213,32)">
     <a href ='list.php' style="text-decoration:none !important;">
       <div class="link"> Back  </div> 
     </a>
 </td>
```

and the code for the style that is been used is

```
.swMntTopMenu
            {
                background-color: #E2E4E5;
                /* float: center;*/
                width: 5%;
                margin-top: 2px;
                padding-bottom: 6px;
                border-bottom: solid 1px #d0ccc9;
            }
```

and

```
.link
            {
                color: #0E0202;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: none;
            }
```

can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: What _not working_ means?

Comment: @DeepKakkar i am using IE 11

Comment: You didn't close your `button` element. Also, you can't have `a` in a `button`.

Comment: @Vucko so instead of anchor  what can i use to redirect to another page

Comment: Link to another page: <a href="list.php">Back</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope this will help

```
<a href ='list.php' style="text-decoration:none !important;"><button style="background-color:rgb(255,213,32)">  <div class="link"> Back </div> </button></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment, You didn't close your `button` element. Also, you can't have `a` in a `button` element.

Either style the `a` to look like a button - here's a nice [CSS button generator](http://css3buttongenerator.com/)

Or put the `button` in a form - [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

In older IE should help declare `A` as block, when you put `div` inside.

```
a {display: block}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this way

```
<form action="list.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Back">
</form>
```